# Tabs in JavaScript and CSS without additional framework/library

Tags: javascript, css, gui

Below's my attempt at creating a simple tab control in JavaScript and CSS, without making use of any libraries or frameworks.

Does this look OK to you guys? Can you see any obvious pitfalls? I believe this should work on all modern browsers, supporting as far back as IE9.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4f51t1f/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabs Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .tabs {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }       
        .tabs * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .tabs > ul > li {
            display: inline;
            background-color: lightGrey;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-bottom-color: white;
            border-width: 1px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        .tabs > ul > li.selected {
            display: inline;
            border-bottom-color: lightGrey;
        }
        .tabs > ul > li:first-of-type {
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1em;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1em;
            border-top-left-radius: 1em;
        }
        .tabs > ul > li > a {
            padding: 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .tabs > div {
            display: none;
        }
        .tabs > div.selected {
            background-color: lightGrey;
            display: block;
            padding: 1em;
            -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
            -moz-border-radius: 2em;
            border-radius: 2em;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
            border-top-left-radius: 0px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body lang="en-US">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
        <div>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
        <div>2 - two</div>
        <div>3 - three</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function indexOfElem(elem){
            var  i = 1; //start index at 1; not 0
            //this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('li:preceding-sibling').length
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType
            var desiredNodeType = elem.nodeType;
            while((elem=elem.previousSibling)!=null) {if(elem.nodeType===desiredNodeType)i++;}
            return i;
        }
        function selectTab(no) {
            if(no.parentNode) {
                no = indexOfElem(no.parentNode);
            }
            //update the tab's link
            var e = document.querySelector(".tabs > ul > li.selected");
            if(e) e.classList.remove("selected");
            e = document.querySelector(".tabs > ul > li:nth-of-type(" + no + ")")
            if(e) e.classList.add("selected");
            //update the tab (div)
            e = document.querySelector(".tabs > div.selected");
            if(e) e.classList.remove("selected");
            e = document.querySelector(".tabs > div:nth-of-type(" + no + ")");
            if(e) e.classList.add("selected");
        }
        function windowOnloadPush(newOnload) {
            var currentOnload = window.onload;
            window.onload = function () {
                if (currentOnload) {
                    currentOnload();
                }
                if (newOnload) {
                    newOnload();
                }
            };
        }
        function loadTabs() {
            var es = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs > ul > li");
            for (var i=0; i < es.length; i++) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var href = document.createAttribute('href');
                href.value = "#";
                var onclick = document.createAttribute('onclick');
                onclick.value = "selectTab(this);";
                a.setAttributeNode(href);
                a.setAttributeNode(onclick);
                while (es[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
                    a.appendChild(es[i].childNodes[0]);
                }
                es[i].appendChild(a);
            }
            selectTab(1);
        }
        windowOnloadPush(function () { loadTabs(); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't edit your code after posting it. It's difficult to critic a moving target. And the fiddle is no longer identical to the code you posted. Also: The fiddle doesn't work because you set the script to be executed "onload". Change it to "No wrap - in <body>".

Comment: @RoToRa; apologies, slipped in a tweak to limit the amount of HTML which needed to be added to get it to work in unison with the JS, instead having the JS create what it could automatically.  Thanks to Schism for updating per your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The comment `start index at 1; not 0` is not helpful; that part of the code is pretty self-explanatory. Rather, you could comment on your reasoning for doing so.
- The spacing in `indexOfElem` is horrendous. Please space out your braces properly. If they enclose only one line, you lose the protection against adding code that you think is in the loop, but in reality is not.
- The use of a `while` loop in `indexOfElem` is alright, but you may find the `for` loop variant more natural. You'll notice that we no longer need to assign `index` to 1, since our loop (which admittedly uses an additional iteration) will take care of it for us.

  ```
  function indexOfElem(elem) {
      var index = 0;
      for (var target = elem.nodeType; elem; elem = elem.previousSibling) {
          if (elem.nodeType === target) {
              index++;
          }
      }
      return index;
  }
  ```
- The `if (no.parentNode)` block in `selectTab` works, but it's kind of icky. It isn't immediately clear that when called with a DOM element, the DOM element will be a direct child of the tab itself. Rather, you can do a more natural check for `typeof no`, and set the `onclick` for the `<a>` to `selectTab(this.parentNode)`.
- In `selectTab`, I'd prefer to write the assignment in the `if` condition. I'd also rather group together the select and deselect code, rather than grouping together the `li` and `div` code.
- Right now, if I `selectTab(-1)`, my tab will be unselected. Instead, it seems like it would be better to check if the index is in bounds first. **This is a behavioural change; it's up to you whether you keep it.**
- You use `elem` in `indexOfElem`, so why use `e` here? For consistency, rename `e` to `elem`. I also renamed `no` to `index`.

  ```
  function selectTab(index) {
      if (typeof index !== "number") {
          index = indexOfElem(index);
      }
      var max = Math.min(
          document.querySelectorAll(".tabs > div").length,
          document.querySelectorAll(".tabs > ul > li").length
      );
      if (index < 1 || index > max) {
          return;
      }

      // deselect the currently selected tab, if applicable
      // this code could be moved into a separate removeClass function, but it's only used twice here so it's not *that* bad...
      var elem;
      if (elem = document.querySelector(".tabs > ul > li.selected")) {
          elem.classList.remove("selected");
      }
      if (elem = document.querySelector(".tabs > div.selected")) {
          elem.classList.remove("selected");
      }

      // select the new tab. no checking required since we already did a range check
      document.querySelector(".tabs > ul > li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").classList.add("selected");
      document.querySelector(".tabs > div:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").classList.add("selected");
  }
  ```
- In `windowOnloadPush`, you should return early if `newOnload` isn't executable. As a matter of style I prefer `x && x()`, but that's your choice.

  ```
  function windowOnloadPush(newOnload) {
      if (typeof newOnload !== "function") {
          return;
      }

      var currentOnload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function() {
          currentOnload && currentOnload();
          newOnload();
      };
  }
  ```
- In `loadTabs`, if you make the first change to `selectTab` that I mentioned, you'll need to change to `onclick.value = "selectTab(this.parentNode);";`.
- Right now you're reassigning all the children of the tab to the `<a>`. That's fine, but if you're just trying to set the text, you can use `textContent` instead. **Again, this is a behavioural change.**

  ```
  function loadTabs() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs > ul > li");
      for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          var href = document.createAttribute('href');
          href.value = "#";
          var onclick = document.createAttribute('onclick');
          onclick.value = "selectTab(this.parentNode);";

          a.setAttributeNode(href);
          a.setAttributeNode(onclick);

          a.textContent = elems[i].textContent;
          elems[i].textContent = "";

          elems[i].appendChild(a);
      }
      selectTab(1);
  }
  ```
- You don't need to use `function() { loadTabs() }`; just use `loadTabs`:

  ```
  windowOnloadPush(loadTabs);
  ```
- Minor stylistic point about your CSS: you can use `0` instead of `0px` or `#888` instead of `#888888`. These aren't big deals though, and it's perfectly fine to leave them as-is.
- You've got `padding: 1em` on `a` in your CSS. This means that there's some extra click space for each tab — clicking on the top of the content changes the tab, which is unintuitive. Instead, use `padding: 0 1em;`. (If you like units, you can use `padding: 0em 1em;`. DON'T use `padding: 0px 1em;` because, well, why would you?)
- You're duplicating `display: inline;` on `.tabs > ul > li.selected`. You can safely remove this.
- Rather than setting `display: none;` on `.tabs > div` and `display: block` on `.tabs > div.selected`, you can just set `display: none;` on `.tabs > div:not(.selected)`. It's up to you to decide which reads better, though I should note that this approach is probably ever so slightly less performant.
- It would be nice if the `<ul>` was auto-generated. You could set a `data-name` or `data-title` or something on each `<div>` and then create the `<ul>` in `loadTabs()`. I didn't implement this, but you should think about it.

[Here's a fiddle with my revised code.](http://jsfiddle.net/gqL1ze52/)

Comment: Great comments, really comprehensive; thanks @Schism.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points:

- You don't need the function windowOnloadPush at all in fact in modern browsers you can use:

  ```
  window.addEventListener("load", loadTabs);
  ```
- You don't need to add your onclick handler as a String (I guess you are doing this for a correct version of `this`). 
  Instead you can use an inline function that you execute immediately to which you pass the element and index. Or you can split this out to its own function. 
  You also don't need to add the attributes explicitly to the `<a>` tag:

  ```
    function loadTabs() {
        var es = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs > ul > li");
        for (var i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
            (function (el,idx) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href= "#";
                a.onclick = function () {
                    selectTab(idx);
                };
                while (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
                    a.appendChild(el.childNodes[0]);
                }
                el.appendChild(a);
            })(es[i],i+1);
        }
        selectTab(1);
    }
  ```

Here's my altered fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dc5v6f6n/2/

One more point:

- Don't set `href="#"`, set it to `"javascript:void(0);"`. This is because linking to `#` has the side-effect of scrolling to the top of the page. Not good if your tabs are not at the very top and the user has scrolled down a bit.

Comment: Thanks @SiKelly.  I'd not come across that approach with inline functions before; nice trick.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified .css for cleaner example

Simplified by removing <a> elements

onclick event attached directly to option so the entire "tab" is active

```
tabs.load = () => {
   var es = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .options > span");
   for (var i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
       (function (el,idx) {
           let st = () => selectTab(idx + 1);
           el.addEventListener('click', st);
       })(es[i],i+1);
   }
   selectTab(2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc5v6f6n/13/

In my own code I generate the html from an array of javascript objects:

```
let tabGen = (options) => {
      html = `<div class="tabs"><div class="options">`;
      html += options.map(o => `<span>${o.tab}</span>`).join('');
      html += `</div>`;
      html += options.map(o => `<div class="option">${o.content}</div>`).join('');
      html += `</div>`;
      return html;
   }

let options = [
    { tab: 'One',   content: '1 - Content of First Tab' },
    { tab: 'Two',   content: '2 - Content of Second Tab' },
    { tab: 'Three', content: '3 - Content of Third Tab' },
    { tab: 'Four',  content: '4 - Content of Fourth Tab' },
];

let html = tabGen(options);
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = html;
tabs.load();
```

And of course the options object is generated as well...